# How are satellites, rocket launches and other space programs affecting the earth’s rotation? How will it be affecting living beings?

Tags: rockets, launch, artificial-satellite, nasa, rotation

Want to know the effects of the active satellite, rocket launches and space programs that affect earth rotation? how? And their effects on living beings due to effect in earth rotation?

Comment: See answers to: [Does launching a device into orbit change earth's orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26733/12102) and also [Are we changing Earth's rotation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34436/12102)

Comment: Highly relevant: https://what-if.xkcd.com/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earth mass is 5.97237E24 kg, the mass of all satellites together is negligible small in comparison.

See the related [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12074/how-has-the-angular-velocity-of-earth-changed-over-the-past-100-years?rq=1).